# How to smooth rectangular signal with high order rate-limiter in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, customization, limit, simulink, derivative

Imagine I have a rectangular reference value for the position/displacement `x` and I need to smooth it.

The math for translatoric movements is quite simple:

```
speed: v = x'
acceleration: a = v' = x''
jerk. j = a' = v'' = x'''
```

I need to limit all these values. So I thought about using rate limiters in Simulink:
[image]
This approach works perfect for ramp signals, as you can see in the following output:
[image]

BUT, my reference signals for `x` are no ramps, they are rectangles/steps. Hence the rate limiters are not working, because the derivatives they get to limit are already infinite and Simulink throws an error. How can I resolve this problem? Is there actually a more elegant way to implement the high order rate-limiters? I guess this approach could be unstable in some cases.

---

continue reading: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240450/3rd-order-rate-limiter-in-simulink-how-to-generate-smooth-triggered-signals)

Comment: Not an expert (certainly not in simulink) but "infinite" slope is probably a misnomer. The computed slope probably just generates an arithmetic overflow or? Is there some way of catching that error and treating it as a trigger?

Comment: @TryHard the error says "input signals to Rate Limiter are neither discrete nor continiuous time signals"

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems absurd, the following approach is working: integration and instant derivation does the trick:
[image] 
leading to:
[image]

More elegant, faster and simpler solutions for the whole smoothing problem are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to differentiate signals in Simulink because of numerical issues, I would advise to start with the higher order derivatives (e.g. acceleration) and integrate, much more robust numerically. This is what the [doc about the derivative block](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/derivative.html) says:

> The Derivative block output might be very sensitive to the dynamics of
>   the entire model. The accuracy of the output signal depends on the
>   size of the time steps taken in the simulation. Smaller steps allow a
>   smoother and more accurate output curve from this block. However,
>   unlike with blocks that have continuous states, the solver does not
>   take smaller steps when the input to this block changes rapidly.
>   Depending on the dynamics of the driving signal and model, the output
>   signal of this block might contain unexpected fluctuations. These
>   fluctuations are primarily due to the driving signal output and solver
>   step size.
>
> Because of these sensitivities, structure your models to use
>   integrators (such as Integrator blocks) instead of Derivative blocks.
>   Integrator blocks have states that allow solvers to adjust step size
>   and improve accuracy of the simulation. See Circuit Model for an
>   example of choosing the best-form mathematical model to avoid using
>   Derivative blocks in your models.

See also [Best-Form Mathematical Models](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/best-form-mathematical-models.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and would expect instabilities caused be inadequate step-sizes at some point (until now it works fine). But my input signals are displacements `x` - so how would you suggest to solve it without derivative blocks? Well the input signals are predefined and I could imagine to write a matlab code providing me a jerk/accelaration/speed input curve instead of `x`, though I actually really wanted to use the Signal Builder within Simulink as it totally fits my needs and then also smooth the curve within simulink. (I wouldn't know how to implement variable step sizes in matlab)

Comment: If the displacement signal is a discrete signal, you can use the Discrete Derivative block. For a continuous signal, you can approximate (and replace) the derivative with a transfer function, such s/(c*s+1) with an approximate choice of c (generally a large value).

Comment: you mean a very small value for `c` right? But then everything get's ridiculously slow, I guess the solver tries to avoid any numerical problems then, while it would just have thrown an error before. I'll try to transform my model into these "Best-Form".

Comment: Oops, yes you're right of course. You might have to adjust your solver settings and use a stiff solver rather than the default ode45.

Comment: I can't figure out how to transform my model into one without derivatives. But actually, it's working for steps and ramps, further thinkable signals would be smoother, no pulses or anything are expected. So there shouldn't be problems? The only improvement I could think of would be a custom third-degree rate limiter, to avoid all the derivatives.

Comment: I found a block called "Switched derivative with proper transfer function approximation for linearization." which works quite well. It actually does the same like suggested by you, but I have no clue why it is so much faster.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know that block even existed!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar. I was looking for a "Smooth Ramp". Here is what I found:

A simpler approach is to combine ramp with a second order lag. Then the signal approachs s-shape. And your derivatives will exist and be smooth as well. Only thing to remember is that the 2nd or lag must be critically damped.

Y(s) = H(s)*X(s) where H(s) = K*wo^2/(s^2 + 2*zeta*wo*s + wo^2). Here you define zeta = 1.0. Then the s-shape is retained for any K and wo value. Note that X(s) has already been hit by a ramp. In matlab or any other tools, linear ramp and 2nd lag are standard blocks.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I think the 'Transfer Fcn' block is what you're looking for.

If you leave the equation in the default form 1/(s+1) you have a low-pass filter which can be tuned to what you need by changing the numerator and denominator coefficients.

Comment: How is this answer related to the question? A transfer function is a linear system, so how should it limit something?