# Determining the block execution order in Simulink

Tags: matlab, block, execution, simulink

I'm working with a Simulink model that contains 2 Level II S-Functions and I need to figure out which of them is executed first during simulation.

Is there a way to know the block execution order of a model and, if possible, alter this order?

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Comment: use triggered subsytems. means put the s-function you want to execute first into a triggered subsystem and send a new trigger signal when the output of your functions is `~=0`. This signal is then the input of the next triggered subsystem. In [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240450/3rd-order-rate-limiter-in-simulink-how-to-generate-smooth-triggered-signals) you can see what I mean. (but topic unrelated)

Answer (score 3):

You can display the sorted order, and assign relative priorities to different blocks, but you cannot set the order as such. For more details, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/controlling-and-displaying-the-sorted-order.html.