# How to use rate limiter with square signal and variable step size in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How to use rate limiter with square signal and variable step size in Simulink?

Here's a screenshot of the model I'd like to set up:

[model](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/16347/rate_limiter_1.png):
[image]

I feed a customized rectangular signal to a rate limiter to avoid vertical slopes.

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I'm using **ode15s**, it's a requirement. Here's the error message Simulink throws:

> Error: Input signals to Rate Limiter '.../Rate Limiter' are neither
>   discrete nor continuous sample time signals. Only discrete or
>   continuous input signals are supported

Quite surprisingly I found a workaroud by adding an integrator directly followed by a derivative. This works:

[workaroud](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/16346/rate_limiter_2.png):

[image]

But it's ugly and I'm getting some very annoying stability issues in some cases. And I doubt very much that it is considered "good practice".

So how is one supposed to use this rate limiter block in such a situation?

John

Comment: My first guess is, that your step function is starting directly at `t=0` - but ode15s needs a value in advance for the rate limiter. Try to start the step a little later. Maybe also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240450/3rd-order-rate-limiter-in-simulink-how-to-generate-smooth-triggered-signals) gives you some inspiration for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for your answers.
I forgot to say I had already checked the sample time with the colour display. It was "Fixed-in-Minor-Step".

Actually it was quite simple. If I get it right, the sample time was not specified or specified in a wrong way in my subsystem. Specifying Continuous in the rate limiter dialog box solved the problem!

thewaywewalk, I'll keep your suggestion in mind. Since I'm using steps a lot it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try [displaying the sample time colours](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html) in your model to check what sample times your signals are using.

Introducing an integrator block will force the signal to become continuous, hence why it works. Maybe using a [Signal Specification](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/signalspecification.html) block or a [Rate Transition](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/ratetransition.html) block with a sample time of `[0, 0]` (for continuous signal, see [Specify Sample Time](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-specify-the-sample-time.html) in the documentation) will achieve the same thing and be slightly more elegant (using the derivative block is not considered good practice).